# Hibernate memory database doesn't update objects

Tags: java, hibernate

my problem:
For testing I use a memory database in hibernate.
I create a new Object called 'event' and don't set any attributes. Then I open a new Session (via sessionFactory) and call session.saveOrUpdate(event).
Then I close the session.

I open a new Session and fetch the event object out of the database

```
(Event result = (Event) session.get(Event.class, subject.getId()));
```

Then I set attributes like: `event.setName("test")`,... and call `session.saveOrUpdate(result)`.
I close the session and then open a new Session.
Event is still there, but attributes not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is a transaction active?

Comment: We use HibernateUtil.ensureTransaction(factory), then save, then commit.